# GTA 5 save file deleted?

Tags: xbox-360, grand-theft-auto-v, xbox-one

So don't ask why but I got GTA 5 on my Xbox One first and then later on my 360. I had advanced pretty far on the story on my One so I bought it on the 360 but when I started up it was the prologue. That was fine. But today when I started it up on my Xbox One it started at the Prologue! I don't know what to do because as of right now my save file is "deleted" or buried. I'm not sure, but please someone help me with restoring the save file or something! Because I'm really disappointed :(

Comment: Try quitting out and restarting the game. Sometimes it just loads the prologue mission again for some reason, so long as you haven't saved over either your auto-save or deleted your manual saves you should be ok.

Comment: Put it as an answer T2HX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qutting and restarting is an option as @TZHX has mentioned in comment but you should also be able to pause and then load a previous game save that exists if you come across the issue again. This is usually a little bit quicker than quitting and starting over.